# Ionic Deeplinks not working for IOS

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, ionic-native

I have used ionic deeplinks https://github.com/driftyco/ionic1-deeplinks-demo 
I am facing an issue in Deeplinking in IOS when view from email client (gmail).

The question is posted here.
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic1-deeplinks-demo/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things here that could be causing you issues:

- There is an error visible in screenshot #2. This is a show-stopper - you need to investigate why you are getting this error.
- While I have heard colleagues say that Universal Links now work reliably in the simulator, I do not beleive this is true. In my experience, Universal Links will start working in the simulator only after the app has first been deployed to a physical device and verified to be working there.
- If I am understanding correctly, you are testing your links from Gmail. Gmail is an app that is known for not supporting Universal Links on iOS. I recommend ruling out as many environmental variables as possible when testing by testing links from the Notes app (test by long-pressing the link and looking for the "open in app" menu option).
- Your AASA file, of course, may not meet Apple's requirements (see https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9/ for details).